# Assign less function based on variable

Tags: css, function, variables, less

I am trying to develop a 'theming engine' in LESS CSS to allow clients to update the colour scheme for their site with the least number of variables. At present we have a variables file where we are assigning the default set, and to shorthand the number of user inputs we utilise the lighten and darken functions a lot e.g.

```
// snippet 1
@grayLight: #999999;
@grayLighter: darken(@grayLight, 10%);
```

Is there a way in which the lighten/darken functions can be assigned as a variable? This way we only need to specify the tone contrast (dark/light or light/dark):

```
// snippet 2 (does not work)
@contrastVerb: darken;
@linkColorHover: @contrastVerb(@linkColor, 10%);//#FFA500;
```

I have tried using Javascript bracket notation to call the function request e.g.

```
// snippet 3 (does not work)
@linkColorHover: `window[@contrastVerb]`(@linkColor, 10%);//#FFA500;
```

An option is pattern-matching:

```
// snippet 4
@tone: light;
.linkColor(light, @color){
    color: lighten(@color, 10%);
}
.linkColor(dark, @color){
    color: darken(@color, 10%);
}

.linkColor(@tone, #f17900);
```

However snippet 4 will is much more verbose than snippets 2 or 3, and will result in a lot of extra code being generated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm in a similar situation regarding user generated themes and I've come up with the following LESS mixin to help me manage colour schemes generated from a few base colours:

```
//LESS 1.3.3
.color (@color, @amount: 100) {
        color: contrast(@color, darken(@color, lightness(@color) * (@amount / 100)), lighten(@color, (100 - lightness(@color)) * (@amount / 100)), 0.5);
    }
```

The above code was written for LESS 1.3.3 which has a different **contrast** function to the LESS version I normally use in Sublime Text 2! If this doesn't give the expected result try:

```
.color (@color, @amount: 100) {
    color: contrast(@color, lighten(@color, (100 - lightness(@color)) * (@amount / 100)), darken(@color, lightness(@color) * (@amount / 100)), 50%);
}
```

This mixin works by generating a contrasting colour based on an input colour and an amount between 0 - 100 inclusive. 100 = full contrast (i.e. black or white); 0 = no contrast (i.e. input colour). E.g.

**LESS**

```
@c: #4f2634;
.c0 {.color(@c, 0)}
.c20 {.color(@c, 20)}
.c50 {.color(@c, 50)}
.c80 {.color(@c, 80)}
.c100 {.color(@c, 100)}
```

**CSS**

```
.c0 {color: #4f2634;}
.c20 {color: #844057;}
.c50 {color: #bf7a92;}
.c80 {color: #e5cad3;}
.c100 {color: #ffffff;}
```

This example obviously generates a text colour so is useful when given a background colour, but the same idea can be re-purposed for border colours etc. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try just add a class in the `<body>` and create css rules (with mixin) to change whatever in the site.

```
<body class="section1"></body>
```

**LESS Demo**:

```
.color-mixin (@color) {
    color: @color;
    .foo{
         background-color: darken(@color, 10%);
    }
    a {
        &:hover{
            background-color: lighten(@color, 30%);
        }
    }
}

.section1 {
    .color-mixin(red);
}
.section2 {
    .color-mixin(blue);
}
```

**CSS Result**:

```
.section1 {
  color: #ff0000;
}
.section1 .foo {
  background-color: #cc0000;
}
.section1 a:hover {
  background-color: #ff9999;
}
.section2 {
  color: #0000ff;
}
.section2 .foo {
  background-color: #0000cc;
}
.section2 a:hover {
  background-color: #9999ff;
}​
```

Comment: Good suggestion. Unfortunately each 'theme' is the entire CSS of the website re-skinned with the same variables. When a user switches theme they get an entirely new several thousand line CSS file. As there is the potential to be ten or more themes I can't see it being feasible to have the class on the body tag switching the styles.

Comment: So the solution in this case has nothing to do with LESS. It would be better load a new CSS file by AJAX.

Comment: You're right - we will end up switching out the CSS when needed. However my original question was: is there a more succinct way than pattern-matching to generate the light/dark switch when changing an elements tone?